# Can (complex) Hadamard matrices of order $n!$ be related to symmetric groups?

Tags: symmetric-groups, hadamard-matrices

For quite a time I wrap my mind about the following:

> Can [(complex) Hadamard matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_Hadamard_matrix) of order $n!$ be related to symmetric groups?

What I tried so far is some numerics and a lot of unfruitful thinking.

Thanks for every reply...

---

Reply to the comments:

I know that the matrix of the discrete Fourier Transform (a special representative of complex Hadamard matrices) is related to abelian groups. 
I hoped that giving the matrix some more degrees of freedom could extend her (let's say) applicability to non-abelian, i.e. symmetric groups.

**EDIT**

I found some papers dealing with the connection of complex Hadamard matrices and Quantum Permutation Groups (e.g. [*QUANTUM PERMUTATION GROUPS: A SURVEY by
TEODOR BANICA, JULIEN BICHON, AND BENOIT COLLINS*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612724.pdf)), but to admit I didn't get what quantum groups are yet.

So if anybody guide me along the path (if there exists one) from complex Hadamard matrices to Symmetric groups via Quantum Permutation Groups I would be ever so happy.

Thanks,

Comment: What reasons are there for thinking there might be a connection.

Comment: @chris I hoping. Is all hope lost?

Comment: Yes, but even hopes have to come from somewhere. I can take any two concepts A and B and ask "are concepts A and B related?" but if I do this randomly I'm just privileging the hypothesis (http://lesswrong.com/lw/19m/privileging_the_hypothesis/). Conjectures should occur to you for reasons of some kind.

Comment: Well, the character table of an abelian group is a complex Hadamard matrix. In design theory, constructions based on abelian groups have generally been very much more fruitful than those based on non-abelian groups. Finally it's not clear what problem you're trying to solve - there are lots of constructions of complex Hadamard matrices.